# Ubuntu Server LTS 16 and HP ProLiant MicroServer

Tags: networking, server, hp, webserver

Internet Connectivity issues since building the server.  I simulated this exact same setup in VMWare and had success.  Anyone else experiencing these issues?

Not really sure where to start looking. If I ping google, I get a range of .7ms to 22ms, which doesn't seem bad to me. – Addohm 2 mins ago   edit

When I'm in an SSH session, every once in a while the whole session just freezes up and becomes unresponsive. The same goes for the website I am building on it as well.

It seems to just constantly drop in and out. I never "lose connection" per say, but at best I might see a very shaky 300KBps on LAN.

Comment: ping your default gateway for few mins then check the to see if ping jumps by much also check if any packets are lost. also check/post your `ifconfig -a` for errors after the ping. Throw some data onto pings too with `ping -M do -s 1472 8.8.8.8`